# Pull docker image and run remote server via Jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, dockerhub, docker-image

I'm building a docker image using jenkins pipeline and push it into docker registry(docker hub), now i want to pull and run this image in other remote server. I am not sure this step (pull&run) must be in jenkins pipline and how.

Comment: Bro have you got the workaround ?
I also have the same need.